# pandas dataframe(DatetimeIndex column) to spark dataframe (datetime format)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python pandas dataframe (pd_df) as follows:

```
    time              count
0  2015-01-31           835
1  2015-02-28          1693
2  2015-03-31          2439
```

which I want to convert to spark dataframe (sp_df). I am using the following command :

When I tried

```
sp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df).
```

The first column was returned in bigint format.

```
time                count
1422662400000000000 835
1425081600000000000 1693
```

I also tried the schema as follows but it didn't work either:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
  StructField("time", StringType(), True),
  StructField("count", IntegerType(), True)])
sp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df, schema)
```

It gave me the error:

```
DateType can not accept object 1422662400000000000L in type <type 'long'>
```

Can anyone suggest me the right way to do it?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because your pandas dataframe column has a data type of `DatetimeIndex` and if you read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) you can see the date is represented internally as int64. Try making your dates strings, then convert to sp_df, with a datatype of `DateType`

Comment: Also why in your `StructField` object are you passing in `"time", StringType(), True`? Why not using `DateType()`?

Comment: Thanks @KatyaHandler ..The idea of converting the datetime to strings helped. In StructField object, earlier, when I am passing in "time", as DateType(), I was getting an error.
Now, After converting the pandas datetime to string and then converting it using the DateType() in StructField() worked.

Comment: This is perfect. Worked for me too. @KatyaHandler, this should be written as its own answer, and then accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Adding here for anyone who had the problem of converting a pandas date column to a spark DateType and not TimeStamp. My df column, although it was a proper `dt.date` type column in the pandas dataframe, automatically converted to a Spark `TimeStamp` (which includes the hour 00:00:00). That was undesirable.

Eventually the solution was changing the way of creating the Pandas dataframe from:

```
df.DataFrame() 
df['date'] = pd.to_date(['2019-01-01', 2019-02-02']).dt.date
```

to doing the same thing, but creating the pandas DataFrame using a dictionary

```
d = {'date': pd.to_date(['2019-01-01', 2019-02-02']).dt.date}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The creation of the dataframe from a dictionary fixed the problem, and now my converted Spark dataframe was able to convert it to a date and note a timestamp column.

It's worth adding that I've also tried to manually convert from Pandas to Spark by adding the mapping: `np.dtype('<M8[ns]'): DateType()`

Comment: sorry, typo - missed a quote: d = {'date': pd.to_date(['2019-01-01', '2019-02-02']).dt.date}

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing in the same situation was to use apply to convert the date column (which for me was an int of year month day, ie 20150129) to a date using apply. Reminder, that apply runs for each row of the table, and returns the result.

```
import datetime
pos_data['TRANSACTION_DATE_converted'] = pos_data.TRANSACTION_DATE.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y%m%d').date() )
```

Then, I used `createDataFrame`, the same as you, and it read in the date. It shows up as

```
TRANSACTION_DATE_converted=datetime.date(2016, 9, 6)
```

in the schema, but this has not yet caused me any issues.

Hive stores the value as a dashed string (ie, `20140129`), so I'll convert the date into a string if it gives me further grief. Though, going through two datatypes is a bit of a silly thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fastest way is to see the bigint as a unix timestamp and then convert it via a spark api function (timestamp or date):

```
from_unixtime(df['time']/1000000000, format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast('timestamp')
```